# Momentjs shows isValid true and console logs correct date and flashed correct .fromNow() but quickly changes to invalid date

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to convert createdAt date in Nuxtjs app retrieved from mongodb through express app, through momentjs. I check if the date is valid, it shows it is valid but when it flashes a correct fromNow format but it becomes invalid date.....-=-

```
<li class="bookchapterlists__list--items" v-for="(chapter, index) in chap" :key="index">
    <nuxt-link
      v-if="chapter.index === 0"
      class="bookchapterlists__list--items__links"
    >Prologue {{chapter.index}}: {{chapter.title}}</nuxt-link>

    <nuxt-link
      v-else
      class="bookchapterlists__list--items__links"
      :to="{path: `${ $route.params.id}/${chapter._id}`}"
    >
      <p
        class="bookchapterlists__list--items__links--title"
      >Chapter {{chapter.index}}: {{chapter.title}}</p>
      <p class="chapter-createdAt">{{chapter.createdAt}}</p>
    </nuxt-link>
  </li>




created() {
    this.$store.commit("book/FORMAT_DATE");
    this.chapters.forEach(chapter => {
      if (chapter.index % 2 === 1) {
        this.rowCount++;
      }
    });
    // console.log(this.rowCount);
  },
  computed: {
    chap: function() {
      return this.$store.state.book.book.chapters;
    }
  }

FORMAT_DATE(state) {
    state.book.chapters.forEach((chapter) => {
      let createdAt = new Date(chapter.createdAt);
      chapter.createdAt = moment(createdAt, 'YYYY-MM-DDYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ', true).fromNow();
      console.log(moment(createdAt, 'YYYY-MM-DDYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ').isValid())
      // console.log(chapter.createdAt);
    })
  }
```

The console log returns true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to do so but

```
<p>{{$moment(chapter.createdAt).fromNow()}}</p>
```

i just installed the nuxt/moment and used it directly in the template!